# Characteristic polynomial $g(x)$ of $\alpha$ over $K$ of a finite extension field $F$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a finite extension of the finite field $K$ and $\alpha \in F$. The mapping $L: \beta \in F \mapsto \alpha \beta \in F$ is a linear transformation of $F$, considered as a vector space over $K$. Prove that the characteristic polynomial $g(x)$ of alpha over $K$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of the linear transformation $T$; that is $g(x) = det(xI - L)$, where $I$ is the identity transform.

Comment: Characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$. I guess you mean minimal polynomial.

Comment: What have you tried?